# How to pass several variables from AppleScript to Shell script?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator

I use Automator to do the following:

1. ask user to choose a folder (as Service action)
2. ask user to choose the name from the list (AppleScript `choose from list ...`)
3. pass the folder chosen and the name chosen to shell-script

I understand how to pass folder chosen from step 1 to step 2. But I don't understand how to pass both variables between steps 2 and 3 (I can pass just one). I tried to `return {answer, input}` at step 2. But shell-script fails with the error `-[__NSArrayM fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000654b80`.

Comment: show your code and eventually a screen of your workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing the list of parameters to a shell script action for example

```
return {"/Applications", "com.apple.application-bundle"}
```

- `$@` represents the flattened list joined by spaces -> `"/Applications com.apple.application-bundle"`
- `$1` represents the first parameter -> `"/Applications"`
- `$2` represents the second parameter -> `"com.apple.application-bundle"`

  and so on...

The shell script can look like

```
mdfind -onlyin $1 "kMDItemContentType == $2"
```

Note: Make sure that the parameters are passed *as arguments* rather than *to stdin* in the shell script action.