# How to pass several variables from Shell Script to AppleScript in Automator?

Tags: bash, shell, applescript, automator

There is an excellent answer for the reverse, [pass several variables from AppleScript to Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45402119/2031849) but I can't find a comprehensive answer for the opposite when there are two or more variables/arguments and or a bash function.

In Automator I am trying to pass variables like so: Run AppleScript > Run Shell Script > Run AppleScript.

1. **Run AppleScript:** which passes a URL as an argument
2. **Run Shell Script:** which uses `"$@"` for that argument

```
/bin/bash serial=$(($RANDOM % 10000)) /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$@"  -c copy  bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "/Path/to/file/movie_$serial.mp4" 2>&1 $! exit 0
```

3. **Run AppleScript:** This is where I need to pick up `stdout`, and the PID of the last executed process `ffmpeg` from Run Shell Script above. I can't seem to get anything. I have tried adding an automator "Storage Variable" but it's not receiving.

Using AppleScript's `Do Shell Script` command I couldn't get `serial=$(($RANDOM % 10000))` to actually put a serial number in the file name `movie_$serial.mp4`.  The file name was literally output as "movie_$serial.mp4", instead of "movie_1234.mp4".

`serial=$(($RANDOM % 10000))` works perfectly in Terminal and in Run Shell Script.  Not sure what I am missing to make it work with "Do Shell Script".

```
do shell script "/bin/bash serial=$(($RANDOM % 10000)); /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i " & link_ & ffmpegOpt & "'" & sPath & "$serial.mp4" & "'"
```

Which returns the following for the "do shell script" call:

```
"/bin/bash serial=$(($RANDOM % 10000)); /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i urlofmovie -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc '/Path/to/file/movie_$serial.mp4'"
```

When using `ffmpeg` the path on the command line the save path has to be in quotes.

Comment: Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your OP correctly, you actually have two different issue here.

1. Not knowing how to provide `input` to a **Run AppleScript** *action* from a **Run Shell Script** *action*.
2. Variable parameter expansion is not occurring for you with: `$serial`

---

## Issue 1:

To return something from a **Run Shell Script** *action* to another *action*. e.g. a **Run AppleScript** *action*, set the last line of the **Run Shell Script** *action* to, e.g.:

```
echo "foobar"
```

Or:

```
printf "foobar"
```

For multiple items use, e.g.:

```
echo "foobar
barfoo"
```

Or:

```
printf "foobar\nbarfoo"
```

---

## Issue 2:

I am not in the position to replicate your `do shell script` *command* at the moment; however, the reason *variable parameter expansion* is not occurring is because the *variable* has *single-quotes* around it.

```
... '/Path/to/file/movie_$serial.mp4'"
```

Expansion will not take place when a *variable* has *single-quotes* around it, so you need to formulate your *command* so it can be expanded. Or in a separate step, process what's necessary to to accomplish the goal.

For example:

```
set sPath to "/path/to/file/movie_"
set serial to ((random number from 0 to 32727) mod 10000) as string
set pathFilename to sPath & serial & ".mp4"
```

Then you can use, e.g.:

```
... & pathFilename's quoted form
```

In your `do shell script` *command* while adjusting the entire *command* to work for you.

In other words, you can get rid of, e.g.:

```
/bin/bash serial=$(($RANDOM % 10000));
```

And:

```
& "'" & sPath & "$serial.mp4" & "'"
```

Comment: I accepted your answer (two years later), but wanted to add a technique for separating shell script input into multiple arguments within Script Editor. See below.

Answer (score 0):

When running a shell script from Script Editor and wanting to return more than one argument as input; and assign those arguments to variables in your Apple Script:

One method I discovered:

Example shell script:

```
SHELL_VAR1=$(date)
SHELL_VAR2=$(whoami)
echo "$SHELL_VAR1","$SHELL_VAR2"
```

The echo command at the end, with a comma for delimiter, will output to Apple Script in this format:

> {"January 21, 2022", "john"}

In the Apple Script:

```
set input to (do shell script "script.sh")
set the text item delimiters to ","
set {var1, var2} to {text item 1, text item 2} of the input

{var1, var2}
```

If there is another, simpler, method I would love to learn it.

Is there a special notation for multiple arguments that Apple Script can use for input?

i.e. `$1` `$2` or something similar